# How to compare a variable value to an array

Tags: python, arrays, compare

In Python, How can I compare two float variable values to ensure if they are within a certain tolerance of each other?

For example:

```
variable = 17.40
array = [14.40, 14.12, 45.50]
```

I need to compare the variable value with the array elements to see which one are close enough.

Comment: Also, could you clarify what it is is you're trying to do?

Comment: Given this question he also asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000021/how-to-compare-float-value-in-in-django I'm guessing the problem is that the numbers in the  array are floats and float comparison doesn't work too well if you use `==` as rounding errors can mess you up(try doing `17.1+0.3==17.4` and you'll get `False`

Answer (score 2):

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000021/how-to-compare-float-value-in-in-django) that you also asked. Here's a piece of code that will check if your variable is in the array(unless that's not what you meant by compare the variable value with the array elements):

```
TOLERANCE=10**-6

def are_floats_equal(a,b):
  return abs(a-b) <= TOLERANCE

def float_in_array(number, array):
  return True in [are_floats_equal(number, a) for a in array]
```

Edit. This might be a bit more efficient to do this way(though less succinct) as we only loop over the array once:

```
def float_in_array(number, array):
  for a in array:
    if are_floats_equal(number, a):
      return True
  return False
```

Comment: My guess is that he asked two questions about the same problem he's facing is and he's not very good at fully expressing what the problem is. But I may be wrong and this is just a guess.

Comment: This is what `any` is for: `any(are_floats_equal(number, a) for a in array)`.  (Although just like you, I'm not sure whether this is what the OP means by 'compare'; for all I know he wants a list of of differences.)

Comment: Oh, nice, I didn't know about any. Been using Python for ages as my go to language and yet I still learn new things about it :-)